# How do I have my Galaxy S3 automatically switch into Driving Mode when I am moving in a car?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, automation, driving-mode

It seems like I read something about how to do this once, but now I can't find it. I thought it was a feature of [On{x}](http://www.onx.ms/), but it doesn't look like the *Galaxy S3* **Driving Mode** is exposed through their API.

What I want is for my phone to automatically switch into **Driving Mode** when it detects I am moving faster than a certain speed (doesn't need to be immediate), and then when I am moving below that threshold switch back (again, after about a minute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using NFC to tell the phone that it should switch itself to driving mode when inserted into the cradle?
You can get nfc stickers for few euro/pounds on ebay..., put one to the back of the cradle, setup your phone and off you go :-)
That probably isn't what you're looking for but still, it's nice and elegant solution ;-)

Comment: Take into account to have NFC always on will probably drain battery.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I like it. I haven't done anything with NFC before. Can it switch back after it stops scanning the NFC, or does that require a different NFC or manual steps.